# Change the font size of the formula in libreoffice impress

Tags: libreoffice

I want to change the font size of the formulas(math) in libreoffice impress. How can I do it?

Answer (score 33):

Double click on the formula and Format -> Font Size.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click of the formula and choose "Position and Size". If the attribute "Size" is selected under "Protect", deselect and enter your expected width and height. You can choose to "Keep ratio" to ensure the width and height are proportional.